# foursquare venues.json structure

Tags: foursquare

Might be missing something but, how can I get the structure of a Foursquare response for a request like https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=...

I want to put the response into a data structure, but most venues aren't fully populated with data.  For example, many venues data have contact info so the contact field is just and empty dict.

I want to know all the fields Foursquare could possibly send back to me for a given venue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete venue description is listed here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue

usually there is a link to the datatypes returned at the bottom of the API endpoint description.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't seem to find/navigate to this info, but that's just what I was looking for.